# Laravel error “Target class [App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController] does not exist.”

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

I'm trying to get to my Reset Password page `change password.blade.php` via a link but it's throwing an error stating: `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController] does not exist.`

This is the route to the page in `web.php`:

```
/**CHANGE PASS */
Route::get('/updatepassword', 'ResetPasswordController@updatePassword');
```

And this is my code in the controller `ResetPasswordController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    /** SUBMIT UPDATE PASSWORD
     *
     * @param request data
     * @redirect user profile view
     */
    
    public function updatePassword(Request $request){
        /*Grab authenticated user record*/
        if(empty($request->id)){
            $id = Auth::user()->id;
        }
        else{
            $id = $request->id;
        }
        /*Update query*/
        $update = User::where('id','=',$id)->first();

        $update->password = bcrypt($request->password);

        $update->save();
        return response($update);
    }

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
}
?>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, so if you see any mistake I will greatly appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: `App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController` is not `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController`

Comment: @lagbox I'm confused by your statement.

Comment: @lagbox Do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 1):

If you check your `RouteServiceProvider` you will see it sets the namespace it uses for Controllers in `web.php` to `App\Http\Controllers`. Your Controller you want to use is in the namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` so you have to specify this additional part of the namespace for it to find it:

```
Route::get('...', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController');
```

Since it was setup to use the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace it will now use the Controller `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController`; without specifying the additional part of the namespace you would end up with `App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController`, which is the current issue you are facing.

`App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController` is not `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController`.

Comment: When I specify that part of the namespace it throws this error `ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist`

Comment: which is a completely different issue and has to do with PHP namespacing in that Controller file... you will need to understand how namespacing works in PHP to continue any further

Comment: @DevMatt I highly suggest this read: https://mattstauffer.com/blog/a-brief-introduction-to-php-namespacing/   if you still have questions after reading this let me know, and good luck

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!